# Waiting for a window (the 2nd time) and pressing Yes

Tags: vbscript

I am running the following script to remove the Novell Client from our computers:

```
On Error Resume Next

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.Run "%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32 ""C:\Program Files\Novell\Client\ncsetup.dll"" NWUninstallClient"
Do Until Success = True
    Success = objShell.AppActivate("Uninstall Novell Client for Windows")
    Wscript.Sleep 200
Loop
objShell.SendKeys "Yes"
```

What this does is launch the uninstall and when the window opens it presses Yes to process with the uninstall. After the uninstall I get another window with the same Title, Uninstall Novell Client for Windows, and this is asking me to reboot. I want to say Yes here but don't know how to add that in.

So basically run the same script above but after the first "Yes", wait for "Uninstall Novell Client for Windows" again and hit "Yes" again.

Does that make sense?

EDIT:
Can I just do this:

```
On Error Resume Next

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.Run "%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32 ""C:\Program Files\Novell\Client\ncsetup.dll"" NWUninstallClient"
Do Until Success = True
    Success = objShell.AppActivate("Uninstall Novell Client for Windows")
    Wscript.Sleep 200
Loop
objShell.SendKeys "Yes"
Do Until Success = True
    Success = objShell.AppActivate("Uninstall Novell Client for Windows")
    Wscript.Sleep 200
Loop
objShell.SendKeys "Yes"
```

Would that work?

Comment: Basically yes, that makes sense. Where is the problem in realizing this?

Comment: I need to know how to do it. Right now it presses Yes once then ends. I need it to wait for the same window one more time then press Yes then exit.

Comment: I added to my post above. Would that work? Thanks, Scott

Comment: What happens when you try it? Does it work, or not? Why do you need to ask us if code you're clearly able to test yourself will work or not?

Comment: It looks like that did work. Sorry, I was not asking anyone to test it but I am still new to all of this and wanted to make sure that was the correct way to do it. Thanks,

Comment: According to the [docs](https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7009974) there is a silent uninstall option, `NWUninstallClient /s`. have you tried?

Comment: Thanks. That works with ir1 and above, happens to be we have the original release....go figure.